# How can integrate tabs into a Bootstrap Carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Right now, I have a proof of concept built of a modal with a tabbed carousel in it. It looks like this:

[image: Modal]

The images for the carousel are populated by a CMS. What I would like to do, is have multiple images tagged as one of the tabs above. When the image shows up in the slideshow, its corresponding tab becomes the active tab. It would also be preferable to be able to click a tab and the slideshow jumps to the first one in the group.

Here's what my current code looks like:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#">Brand</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Print</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Web</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Marketing</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="this-carousel-id" class="carousel slide">
    <!-- class of slide for animation -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        {foreach from=$images item=slide name=foo} {if $smarty.foreach.foo.first}
        <div class="item active">
            <!-- class of active since it's the first item -->
            <img src="{$slide->file}" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <p>
                    Caption text here
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>{else}
        <div class="item">
            <!-- class of active since it's the first item -->
            <img src="{$slide->file}" alt="">
            <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
            <ul>
                <li style="list-style: none">{foreach from=$slide-&gt;fields item=imagefield}
                </li>
                <li>fieldname '{$imagefield.name}' has value: '{$imagefield.value}'
                </li>
                <li style="list-style: none">{/foreach}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>{/if} {/foreach}
    </div><!-- /.carousel-inner -->
    <!--  Next and Previous controls below
        href values must reference the id for this carousel -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#this-carousel-id" data-slide="prev">‹</a> <a class="carousel-control right" href="#this-carousel-id" data-slide="next">›</a>
</div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

Any suggestions on how I could go about this?

Comment: You don't want tabs, you want to style the list of `.carousel-indicators` so that it *looks* like tabs.

Comment: @Blazemonger Well, that was my thought too. The thing is, every category has more than one picture so indicators wouldn't work..

Comment: That doesn't seem to align with what you wrote in your question. And either way, I'm afraid your question is likely to be closed as "too broad" without some code that you've already tried.

Comment: @Blazemonger Thanks for the heads up. Will revise.